# GPGPU Android Emulator (Renderscript / OpenCL)

Tags: android, opencv, android-emulator, amd-processor

More specifically, I'm wanting to run OpenCL / Renderscript code in an Android Emulator that actually runs on my computer's GPU instead of CPU. Unluckily I'm using an AMD CPU and GPU.

I know that AMD has OpenGL ES support (and everything supports OpenCL pretty much) via SDKs but that's as far as I've gotten on that front - the only OpenCL / Renderscript information I've found regarding emulators is that they either don't work at all or, if I had an Intel CPU, I could install OpenCL in the emulator but it would only use the CPU (and frankly I wouldn't be surprised if behind the scenes my emulator(s) aren't already doing this - OpenCV runs without incident but OpenCL-Z says there's no OpenCL support).

Is there some way to send the commands from the emulator to my OS and have it automatically run? The only ways I've come up with involve saving and loading a text file which isn't likely to be faster (or good for my hard drive) given I'm running 2 Emulator Instances.

I found some mention of RenderScript being supported in the official emulator but said emulator isn't meant for my use-case and I strongly doubt that it's going to use my GPU.

I'm using Memu at the moment because Bluestacks 3 uses more resources when running 2 instances and the 2nd instance doesn't work very well with adb commands / root for some reason - it thinks it's working but it doesn't do anything. If there's a faster emulator when it comes to running 2 instances I'm sure it would help but oddly enough comparing them is difficult and time consuming (especially when every one of them is like "No, I'M the fastest - look at MY bar graphs!" lol) and ultimately I believe my problem to be with OpenCV not getting GPU acceleration (because it runs much faster on my phone) and not the emulator's base speed.

I have AMD's virtualization features enabled (confirmed with Leomoon or w/e) and they're enabled in the manager for Memu. Perhaps this is already working behind the scenes, then? Either way, emulation costs increase by 10% per instance once the OpenCV stuff comes into play (taking it from 60 to 80%+)

Answer (score 0):

Use a language (like Python) and send commands via ADB. Python can hook into OpenCL and OpenCV; ADB can be used to get the Framebuffer for screenshots or Python can just capture the emulator's window render.

Alternatively, a connection can be made using SocketIO (Flask Socket IO and Javascript's client socket IO in my case) and they can communicate that way. Confirmed via the browser on the emulator and real device. Every emulator has ports to communicate to your native OS. I ultimately chose not to go this route as it's a little convoluted (2 servers, different languages, no better than ADB over LAN) but it's an option. Java (iirc) also runs SocketIO just fine and would likely be a decent option for many devs who are familiar with the language and wish to run some stuff natively on Android Devices.

Feeling physically ill atm and typing on a phone so my apologies for the present lack of examples and assistance. Hopefully I can catch the time to address this but, frankly, there are few use cases for this outside of the one I'm presently targeting and it's quite niche to begin with.